# SwiftUI - How to change/access @Published var value via toggle from View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making a simple password generation app. The idea was simple.

There are 2 toggles in the View that are bound to **ObservableObject** class two **@Published** bool vars. The class should return a different complexity of generated password to a new View dependently on published vars true/false status after clicking generate button.

Toggles indeed change published var status to true/false (when I print it on toggle) and the destination view does show the password for false/false combination but for some reason, after clicking generate, they always stay false unless I manually change their value to true. Can toggles change permanently the value of @Published var values somehow?

I can't seem to find a suitable workaround. Any solutions how to make this work?

**MainView**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

@ObservedObject var manager = PasswordManager()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView() {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $manager.includeNumbers) {
                    Text("Include numbers")
                        .italic()
                }
            }
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $manager.includeCharacters) {
                    Text("Include special characters")
                        .italic()
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: PasswordView(), label: {
                Text("Generate")
                })
        }
        .padding(80)
    }
}
```

**PasswordManager**

```
import Foundation

class PasswordManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var includeNumbers = false
    @Published var includeCharacters = false

    let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    let specialCharacters = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%"]

    var password: String = ""

    func generatePassword() -> String {
    
        password = ""
    
        if includeNumbers == false && includeCharacters == false {
            for _ in 1...5 {
                password += letters.randomElement()!
            }
        }
        else if includeNumbers && includeCharacters {
            for _ in 1...3 {
                password += letters.randomElement()!
                password += numbers.randomElement()!
                password += specialCharacters.randomElement()!
            }
        }
        return password
    }
}
```

**View that shows password**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct PasswordView: View {

    @ObservedObject var manager = PasswordManager()

    var body: some View {
        Text(manager.generatePassword())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your `PasswordView` creates its own `PasswordManager`. Instead, you need to inject it from the parent view.

You should never initialise an `@ObservedObject` inside the View itself, since whenever the `@ObservedObject`'s `objectWillChange` emits a value, it will reload the view and hence create a new object. You either need to inject the `@ObservedObject` or declare it as `@StateObject` if you are targeting iOS 14.

`PasswordView` needs to have `PasswordManager` injected from `MainView`, since they need to use the same instance to have shared state. In `MainView`, you can use `@StateObject` if targeting iOS 14, otherwise you should inject `PasswordManager` even there.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PasswordView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var manager: PasswordManager

    init(manager: PasswordManager) {
        self.manager = manager
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(manager.generatePassword())
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    @StateObject private var manager = PasswordManager()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: $manager.includeNumbers) {
                        Text("Include numbers")
                            .italic()
                    }
                }
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: $manager.includeCharacters) {
                        Text("Include special characters")
                            .italic()
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: PasswordView(manager: manager), label: {
                    Text("Generate")
                })
            }
            .padding(80)
        }
    }
}
```